# query 2 columns with different amount of rows from different datatable in same database

Tags: sql, ms-access

How do i query to find 2 columns with different number of rows from different datatable in the same database.

I tried to do it like this but it merges the data.

```
SELECT core.[Close Date for core], care.[close date for care] FROM core, care;
```

Example source data and desired output:
[image: example]

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? How are tables related? Edit question to show sample data and desired output.

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (**without errors**), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: I added a image of my desired output.

Comment: But all dates are identical. So which records/fields to put where?

Comment: I would like to make a new table and in the table there are only dates. I have edited the names of the columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a union query, *Query1*, to list the users:

```sql
Select Id, User
From core
Union    
Select Id, User
From care
```

Then use this with a left join to each of the tables:

```sql
SELECT 
    Query1.Id,
    Query1.User,
    core.[Close Date] As [Close Date for core],
    care.[Close Date] As [Close Date for care]
FROM 
    (Query1
LEFT JOIN
    core ON core.Id = Query1.Id)
LEFT JOIN
    care ON care.Id = Query1.Id;
```

Output *Query1*:

[image]

Output *Query2*:

[image]

Comment: The first query gives me ID with empty user column. The second query gives all empty fields

Comment: No. They provide the output you requested. See edited answer, please.